# How to implement a four Mecanum wheel robot kinematic model practically in code?

Tags: mobile-robot, odometry

> [image: Kinematic model of 4 wheel mecanum drive robot]

Above is the kinematic model of a four wheeled robot from [Omnidirectional Mobile Robot – Design and Implementation](https://cdn.intechopen.com/pdfs/465/InTechOmnidirectional_mobile_robot_design_and_implementation.pdf).

My question is how to use these kinematic equations while coding on a micro controller? I have an IMU and wheel encoders: How to use these sensor data and achieve odometry for the robot?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* XXX, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to **include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see.** Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @50k4 , even I had the same doubt, can u please clarify regarding the last comment by OP? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[image: Update equations]

I think I figured out, please someone confirm if i'm right

In the above equations, w1, w2, w3 and w4 are taken from the wheel encoders at each time step and (x,y) of the robot are updated as per the equations and using an IMU orientation of the robot is calculated and updated according to the equations at each time step.

Comment: no, heading is also taken from the encoders. IMU is not included here, that comes after you have the Cartesian velocities, as a separate sensor fusion step.

Comment: How to take heading using encoders? What equations to use

Comment: The last one, omega z calculates the rotational velocity (which i falsely called heading previously)

Comment: What are the equations to calculate the robot angular velocity (omega z) using wheel encoder data?

Comment: Tha last one you posted. Says angular velocity explocitly

Comment: Rotational and angular are the same things in this context

Comment: @50k4 can you confirm on my last comment?

Comment: No, I do not understand your last comment.

Comment: https://ibb.co/VpHdd6Q, is this how the angular velocity of the robot is calculates, Dl and Dr are the distance covered by the left and right wheels respectively in each time step and L is the distance between the wheels. I used the same equation while Implementing odometry for a Differential drive robot. Is it same in the case of mecanum wheeled robot?

Comment: The paper you referenced and the equations you have posted cover angular velocity. Why not just use that? They might simplify to the equations you have posted, do the math and find out!